# Record Audio from Microphone + Music Playback

Tags: ios, audio

I can record videos while Music continues playing via `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` + `AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat` + `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers`, but the recorded video only contains the audio from the microphone input!

Is there some way, in the case music is playing from Music, that I can mix this audio into my video file?

Comment: If you have access to the music file (i.e. can load it into an AVAsset with it's url) then you would need to use AVFoundation to export a video that has the original video you recorded plus the audio you want to add to it. There are a few posts about Merging audio with video that you could check out

Comment: @AlanS ya no access to the file. just wondering how Snapchat accomplishes this when you happen to be playing music in the Music app.